# JSF application with hibernate and c3p0 freezes after a few actions

Tags: hibernate, c3p0

I'm using hibernate 4.2.4 with c3p0 0.9.2.1 in a JSF 2.0 application. Everything is working, but if 5 users at once doing some actions inside the application it freezes after a few minutes. Other applications (portlets) inside the same container can still be accessed, CPU and RAM usage is normal.

Perhaps all connections of the c3p0 connection pool are in use and aren't released after usage?! But how can I check, if this is the problem?

Some threads at stackoverflow.com tell to use `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` and `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces`. Do I have to put it like the following into my hibernate.cfg.xml?

```
<property name="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout">5</property>
<property name="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces">true</property>
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml is:

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">2</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, first thing: maxPoolSize (hibernate.c3p0.max_size) of two is not a great idea. It should "work", but expect a lot of waiting if you have any significant concurrent access.

Re configuration syntax: it'd be more like...

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces">true</property>
```

Verify the c3p0 config you want gets through by examining the config dump (at INFO) on pool initialization.

Alternatively, use JMX to examine the pool during the freeze.

Comment: max_size of "2" was for testing purpose. Usually my application runs with 20. I don't know if this is a recommended number. Do I have to use a max_size?

Comment: How do I enable conifg dump at initalization? There is no output from c3p0 on console while tomcat is starting.

Comment: Discovered some c3p0 entries in my log4j application log. So your suggestion works!

Comment: i'm glad! (i hope it ultimately helps you resolve your problem...)